# How to have Apache 2.2 use an earlier version of libapr?

Tags: apache-2.2, libraries, web-server

I'm using a module in Apache that requires `libapr-1.0.3.8`, which is in my `lib/` directory, but it appears my installation (via MacPorts) is using `1.0.4.5`.

Can I force Apache to use the earlier version without breaking? If so, how would I go about specifying this?

Comment: Which module requires this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inclined to think that your concerns are unfounded -- the differences between the `libapr` versions you've got should be non-existent.  The big `soname` change for `libapr` was way back in version 0.9, and since you've got a newer version, it should be backwards compatible with the older version your module needs.

If you do think you need to force it, I'd say you *might* be able to force it in with `LD_PRELOAD` without breaking, but in practice I wouldn't risk it on a production site.  You *certainly* can't load both versions at once, you'll get symbol collisions.  I'd be fixing the module.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree that it's hideous. It's coming from FileMaker's mod_jk_fm as part of their PHP API. I get this when I try to include it in httpd.conf: `Symbol not found: _apr_stat$INODE64`. When I `nm -arch all libapr-1.0.4.5` looking for `apr_stat` I don't get the INODE64, but I do in 1.0.3.8. Is there another way around this? Appreciate the help!

Comment: I think you've got an archicture mismatch in your libraries -- what does `file` say about the two libraries?  If my surmise is correct, force-feeding the wrong one to Apache isn't going to do you any good.

Comment: results of `file`: 1.0.3.8 is universal binary with 3 architectures (x86_64, i386, ppc7400), while 1.0.4.5 is `dynamically linked shared library x86_64`. Is there a way to rebuild apache with the additional architectures? I'm so clueless about architecture stuff.

Comment: ignore my last question for now. i'm trying a reinstall with +universal specified in macports to see if it works. if not, i may need to take my question to a macports forum. thank you!